# Cron job to move many rows between MySQL table

Tags: cron, mysql

I have a main database that stores up to 5'000 new rows per day.

I want to have a second database that only contains the latest 30 days worth of data at any time.

Therefore I plan to set up a cron job that regularly dumps the rows older than 30 days and copies the new ones.

What would be the best design for the copying part?

- Copying on the fly with MySQL alone
- An MySql export to a txt file, then an MySql import, then deleting the temporary file
- A php script that iterates through the rows and copies them one by one

I want robustness and minimum amount of CPU/memory usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest and most robust way is to perform the transfer directly in MySQL. Here are the steps involved:

First, create the second table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS second.last30days LIKE main_table;
```

Next, insert the records 30 days old, or newer:

```
INSERT INTO 
second.last30days
SELECT
*
FROM
main_table
WHERE
created >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAYS
ORDER BY created;
```

Lastly, delete the records older than 30 days:

```
DELETE FROM 
second.last30days
WHERE
created < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAYS
ORDER BY created;
```

It would be advisable to not run the `INSERT` and `DELETE` statements at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

if the databases are both hosted on the same server. just use an `insert ... select` statement.
that way you minimize everything. 1 query, and done.

[MySQL 5.0 - 13.2.5.1. INSERT ... SELECT Syntax"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)